# Is Black Panther debuting in Captain America: Civil War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

Does ***Captain America: Civil War*** feature the first appearance of **Black Panther** in the Marvel Cinematic Universe? Or has he appeared in previous movies, or perhaps in one of the Marvel TV series like *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*?

Comment: FYI Deadpool is not in the MCU.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Yes, Captain America: Civil War is the Black Panther's first appearance in the MCU

Kevin Feige discussed this decision with [SuperHeroHype](http://www.superherohype.com/features/345425-kevin-feige-on-ant-mans-place-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe#zr1taOJK28j2ws5Z.99) last year:

> SHH: **You’ve already announced a “Black Panther” movie and he’s going to be introduced in “Civil War”** but are you going to try to do more movies like “Ant-Man” or even “Thor” where you’re introducing the character in their own solo movie, or will you continue to play with introducing the characters in an earlier movie?
>
> Feige: It always varies, it really does. It always depends on how the timing works out. It depends on what stories we want to tell. In the case of “Civil War,” we needed a third party, we needed a character who wasn’t on either Captain America or Iron Man’s side, which is why we went, “You know what? **We’re doing a Black Panther movie, but it would actually be smart to have him fill this role we need in Civil War and introduce him here first.”** So it always just depends on the story and the way we want to tell the story.

Previous to *Captain America: Civil War*, there has been no mention of T'Challa (the Black Panther). Wakanda, his home country was mentioned briefly in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* as the source of Vibranium.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, he is debuting in *Captain America 3: Civil War*.

We are introduced to his character and given a brief explanation of his background in the movie. (He actually plays a pretty significant role). We are given basically the same treatment for Spider-Man's debut, also in this movie.

Both characters have solo movies coming out later: *Spider-Man* in 2017 and *Black Panther* in 2018.

Answer (score 8):

I believe Marvel Studios President Kevin Feige said this,

> In the case of Civil War, we needed a third party, we needed a character who wasn’t on either Captain America or Iron Man’s side, which is why we went, 'You know what? We’re doing a Black Panther movie, but it would actually be smart to have him fill this role we need in Civil War and introduce him here first.' So it always just depends on the story and the way we want to tell the story.

But, to answer the question yes it is the first time.